# Limiting selectable filter values in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008, mdx

I have a SSRS challenge. Hope someone out there can help me out.
I have an analysis services data set where is use a date filter as a parameters.
When I deploy my report all the dates from my date dimension are displayed as selectable values in the filter drop down.
It would be nice if the users could only select the filter values where there are actually data in the data set.

Can anybody tell me how I can make reporting services limit the selectable filter values to the ones with measure date?

Thanks!

Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would have to write a query which returns those date which have data, then use it in the parameter as specify available values from query.